# What is recommended for monitoring traffic to my asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications

I have a asp.net 3.5 application hosted on IIS 7.0. I'm looking for a comprehensive system to monitor traffic, down to page level minimum. Does .net have any specific tools or is it better to write my own, or what systems/software is freely available to use

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics)**.  Its a small piece of Javascript code that is inserted before the  tag.  Its based on Urchin analytics tracking software which Google bought.  They've been doing this for a long long time.

As long as your site is referenced using a fully qualified domain name, Google Analytics can track what you need.  It's got lots of flexibility with the filter mechanism as well (let's you rewrite URLs based on query string parameters, etc.)

LOTS of functionality and well thought out as well as a pretty good API if you need to do tracking on things other than clicks.

Comment: Will there be any issues with https certificate?

Comment: No.  If your URL is https, Google will use https to communicate as well.  Remember, there isn't any communication between the web browser client and your server for this tracking.  The web browser basically makes a call to Google with the data for URL tracking.

Comment: thanks, added the javascript, waiting for the tracking to kick in now

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the IIS logs, you can use a log analyzer to interpret the data. An example is the free AWStats analyzer:

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

An alternative (and one I recommend) is Google Analytics (http://www.google.com/analytics). This relies on you embedding a small chunk of Javascript in each page you want tracking, then Google does the grunt work for you, presenting the results in an attractive Flash-rich site.

I'd suggest trying both and seeing which suits your needs. I'd definitely recommend against rolling your own system, as the above solutions are very mature and capable. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a client-side / javascript tracking service (such as Google Analytics but there are other good free alternatives out there) because it runs even when the user clicks the back button and the previous page (on your site) is loaded from the browser cache and not the server. The IIS won't "see" the reload since no request is made to it.